# SQL database schema design tags

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-normalization, database-relations

Here is the database schema I just drew up.

[image: my schema]

- A beer belongs in a single category.
- A category is composed of multiple tags.
- A beer is tagged by multiple tags.
- A tag can be used with multiple beers (many to many).

Constraint:
You cannot add tags to a beer that does not belong to the category those tags are associated with.

Is this design correct regarding the constraint? Is this something I should handle in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your constraints, yes, this design is correct.

This design also requires that each tag can belong to only a single category. No many-to-many between category and tag.

> You cannot add tags to a beer that does not belong to the category those tags are associated with.

This rule must be enforced through app logic. Nothing in the database design prevents a beer being assigned to tags of categories not assigned that beer. Not a flaw in your design, just the way it is. A relational database design cannot itself enforce every kind of rule or constraint.

Given how vague the idea of `user`, `tag`, and `category` is in your brief description, there is no further advice to be given or further thoughts to consider as we cannot understand the business problem/context.

Comment: Thank your for your replay. As you said, the database schema does not prevent a beer being assigned to tags of categories not assigned that beer. That was the reason of the post. I thought this part had to be handled at the database level and couldn't figure out to do it.